# Get a list of object properties from list of objects in python

Tags: python

I will give you my specific example but this is a general python question.

I have a list of apscheduler job objects [Link](http://packages.python.org/APScheduler/modules/job.html) I am trying to figure out what is the most efficient way to get a list of the apscheduler job property, 'kwargs' from my list of apscheduler jobs.

I know I can just iterate through the whole list and make a new list of kwargs, but I was wondering if there is a more efficient/ cleaner way to do this in python, since I am new to it. Thanks!

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

schedule = Scheduler()
jobs = schedule.get_jobs() #jobs is a list of apscheduler jobs
jobs_kwargs = ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out with a little help from a coworker. This can be done by using map:

```
from apscheduler.scheduler import Scheduler

schedule = Scheduler()
jobs = schedule.get_jobs() #jobs is a list of apscheduler jobs
jobs_kwargs = map(lambda k: k.kwargs, jobs)
```

This is supposedly more efficient as it parallel processes the task(I still have to look into it for more information). Thanks for the suggestions though!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you pretty much said it:

```
jobs = schedule.get_jobs()
jobs_kwargs = [j.kwargs for j in jobs]
```

As far as I know, there's really no "cleaner" way than that.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John on this.

Maybe a suggestion:

If your jobs objects are all of the Schedule class type, dynamically append to the class attribute (not self but cls) i.e. **kwargs** each job object kwargs whenever one gets instantiated, so that at anytime, you could read from that class attribute. via i.e. a classmethod called i.e. schedule.get_gwargs(cls).

But I am not sure  this brings anything better than a simple list comprehension.